# Next step for updating iphone database from web server?

Tags: iphone, web-services, sqlite

I have an iphone app with an SQLite db. I also have a MySQL database on a web server that the app will call to get new records on app start up. I created a web service that will receive the date of  latest record in the app database and do the query to pull all the new records.  The new records will be put into an array and JSON encoded to go back to the app.

Do I then put the new records into NSDictionary and write them to the app's SQLite database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes when you received results from API in JSON you need to create `NSDictionay` or `NSArray` to do this you've to need [JSON parser](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) for iOS. After parsing the JSON you can insert it into your SQLite DB.

Comment: If you can go iOS 5 only, there is now a built-in JSON framework.

Comment: This you just have to create NSDictionay or NSArray and insert to your SQLite DB tables